# headphones jack (audio+microphone) not detected, shown as unplugged and not fully working on HP laptop - Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: sound, hp, microphone, audio-jack, hda-intel

i know there are a lot of similar questions but I've not managed to solve my problem trying to follow them. Here I'll try to be ad detailed as possible hoping to get some help, sorry for the long post. (also this is my first ever question, if anything's not right please be kind)

info:

- Laptop model: HP HP 255 15.6 inch G9 Notebook PC
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, 64-bit, Gnome 42.5, Wayland (deleted windows, NOT dual boot)
- Headphones used are standard Android headphones with microphone. In Windows 11 they worked perfectly

problem:
When I insert the headphones' jack it is not detected by the laptop, which plays audio both from the speakers and in the headphones. By selecting the headphones as output on `pavucontrol` it works and it stops playing to the speakers, but there's no way to select and use the headphones microphone which is detected and works (green bar moving when speaking) but it is shown as unplugged. I'd consider the problem fixed if by connecting the headphones' jack the PC would automatically switch the audio output and if I could record and speak with the headphone microphone in online videocalls (Google Meet on Firefox); I already managed a workaround by changing manually output and using the internal digital microphone, but I'm not really satisfied...
Also if I boot the pc with headphones inserted I get "Dummy Output" as the only output

images and attempts made so far:

- as mentioned I tried using `pavucontrol`, the headphones are shown as unplugged, switching output works, but the microphone does not, i also tried unlocking the channels and turning of one of them. I tried muting the laptop microphones or set the headphones' one as fallback but it does not work

[pavucontrol configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JzFe.png)
[pavucontrol output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A0V4.png)
[pavucontrol input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lotTZ.png)

- I've tried `alsamixer` Enabling automute, but since the jack is not detected it still does not work

[Alsamixer selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvUC4.png)
[Alsamixer mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmIll.png)

- I've tried killing and restarting `pulseaudio` and also reinstalling `alsa-base pulseaudio`, I also did `purge timidity-daemon` and `alsa force-reload` which executes but get stuck without any error or messages after a few lines.
- I've also edited `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` adding `options snd-hda-intel model=....` trying various options from kernel.org under the section "ALC22x/23x/25x/269/27x/28x/29x (and vendor-specific ALC3xxx models)" I do not remember everything I've tried, but definitely: laptop-dmic, headset-mic, dell-headset-multi, alc221-hp-mic, alc233-eapd, alc295-hp-x360 (each one separately and some in combinations)

for info running `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` returns:

```
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC236
```

- Finally I've tried using `hdajackretask` but did not fully understood it. even showing unconnected pins there is not the option "Microphone" under any of them, and also "apply now" does not work because it gives the "device is busy" error.
  [hdajackretask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNoUs.png)
  [hdajackretask unconnected pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGx48.png)
- I've also found this thread [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/HP-Spectre-x360-with-Ubuntu-Plugging-in-Headphones-doesn-t/td-p/5543183) but I was not able to use HDA-analyzer, the link leads to a 404 and I'm not that good with github and python programs to understand what I could do to run the program.

thank you everyone for your attention, any help is appreciated! :)